# jQuery to reset the selection in a webpage / specific question of a Qualtrics Survey

Tags: javascript, jquery, survey, qualtrics

I am new (and struggling) with some JavaScript so would be grateful for some help.  There are a number of options to complete the below process so I'll explain what I'm trying to do at a high level first.

I have a Qualtrics Survey which I would like to use a Hot Spot with a picture of a map with a number of locations on it.  I've created several regions.  During the survey the user is asked to select a location.  This is great but I'd like to ask if they have selected the correct location.

**Option 1:**  Use JavaScript to listen out for a click event on the page and pops up a prompt (with the options: ok // cancel) confirming their choice.  If they click ok, the survey advances to the next page.  If Cancel, then the current selection(s) is / are undone or the page reloads with nothing selected.  I found some code [How to create a popup window in a Qualtrics Survey Question](https://www.qualtrics.com/community/discussion/1654/a-code-for-a-pop-over-or-pop-up-window-to-prompt-participants-to-check-their-answers) to do the prompt window as a starting point (see below).  However I have two problems:

1) I can't retrieve the location value (it says unidentified)
2) I don't know how to reset the page / question so that no items are selected.

**Option 2:**  Let the user choose a location (I've limited it to 1 location in the hot spot settings). 
 In the next page (ie Question), I can use piped text to retrieve which item was selected `${q://QID25/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoicesForAnswer/2}` and can ask the user if this was the right location.  I'd like some JavaScript to listen for a click and then understand whether Yes or No was selected.  If Yes, then proceed to the next page.  If No, then proceed to the previous page.  My problem is

1) how to retrieve the value Yes / No
2) how reset the Hot Spot selections.

To help here's a little picture of the hotspot (blurred intentionally!):

[image: Q25 Hot spot showing location user needs to select]

==========================================================
**Option 1 code (courtesy of above link)**
*Note: I am not a expert is JavaScript, I believe there are some pieces of code below which aren't actually required but I've left them in, however please feel free to flag these so that I can learn!*

Step 1: Paste the following code in the look and feel -> advanced -> add custom css.  This is to allow the creation of an extra button that can be used to invoke a script.

```
#CustomButton{
border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    transition: background .3s;
    background-color: #c32432;
}
```

Step 2: Q25 Paste the following code in the js(onload) of the question to call up the prompt box when the first click on the page happens (ie.  this process effectively clicks on the customButton which invokes the js code in Step 3)

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
        this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        $('CustomButton').click();
    };

});
```

Step 3: Q25 Paste the following code in the js(onready) of the question for which you want the popover to occur:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
const that=this;
    this.hideNextButton();
    var btn = jQuery('<div id="Buttons"><input id="CustomButton" class="NextButton Button"  title="  Next  " type="button" name="NextButton" value=" Next  "  aria-label="Next"></div>') //I can add hidden="True" if I wanted to hide this button on the screen.
    jQuery('#Buttons').append(btn);

    jQuery('#CustomButton').on('click', function(){
        var txt;
        var e= jQuery("[id='QR~QID25']").val() //<=== need help to retrieve location selected
        var r = confirm("You chose this location, please confirm this is correct? "+e);
         if (r == true) {
                 that.clickNextButton();
         } else {
                 //how do I clear the selection(s) / reset the page?
          }

    });

});
```

==========================================================
**Option 2 code**

Step 1: Q25 Paste the following code in the js(onload) of the question to move to the next question automatically upon the first click

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
        this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        $('NextButton').click();
    };

});
```

Next Question (Q28) prompts user to confirm the choice is correct (see pic) :
[image: Q28]

Step 2: Q28 Paste the following code in the js(onReady) of the question.
*Note: This code is not the end product but I'm trying to work out the syntax to get the value in the first place.  The code doesn't work at present as it does not give me anything in the console.  I am also a little unsure if I've got the ID correct.  in Short I'm stuck on getting the Yes / No value and also as per Option 1 stuck on how to reset the hot spot selections on the previous page.*

Initial source: [Retrieve selected answer without need for piped text](https://www.qualtrics.com/community/discussion/231/using-multiple-choice-question-text-to-prefill-text-box-of-another-question)

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    document.getElementById("QR~QID28").onchange = function(element){
       //console.log(element); // use console to look at element to find what you need in the question;
       var ele_var1=element.target.value.toString(); // gets selected option value from question;
       var ele_var=element.currentTarget[ele_var1].Text; // gets text value of selected option;

       /*document.getElementById("QR~QID6").value=ele_var; //updates text question;*/

if (var == "Yes") {
                 that.clickNextButton();
         } else {
                that.clickPreviousButton();
          }

   }
});
```

In the DevTools window screenshot (see pic below), I've shown that I've selected 'YES' but I don't think the code is pulling out the answer.  This is where my lack of knowledge of HTML and JS is stopping me so would appreciate some help.

[image]

If you got to the bottom of thsi question - thanks very much for reading - and thanks even more so if you're able to reply and give me some guidance! :)

Thanks

Rod

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is not possible because the region definitions are inside a SVG.

On Option 2 you have a number of errors in your script. Besides, you are doing it it hard way. Also, you need to hide the next/previous buttons and have the question on its own page. Try:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
  var qobj = this;
  jQuery("#Buttons").hide();
  var q = jQuery("#"+qobj.questionId);
  q.find("input:first").click(function() { qobj.clickNextButton(); });
  q.find("input:last").click(function() { qobj.clickPreviousButton(); });
});
```

Comment: Hi @T.Gibson.  Thanks for the better script for Option 2.  It looks non selective and just searches all questions on the same page (hence the need for it to be on one page?).  How could you double check that 'first' meant yes and 'last' meant no?  Would there be a way to retrieve the value in order to check and then use a If loop?  Sorry this is veering back to my original code but knowing how to do it both ways would certainly help my learning. :)  PS.  spotted a missing " just after 'last'

Comment: Re SVG... (sorry what does that mean?)  so you can't get the region name value without submitting and moving to the next page.  However, can the page still be reset though and selections removed?  Thanks.

Comment: It is selective; it only searches the current question (this). The question should be on its own page because you are clicking the Next/Previous buttons based on the answer. First and last go by the order of the elements on the page.  Unless you randomize (which you wouldn't do with a Yes/No question), they will always be in that order. So, checking is a waste of time. I added the missing quote. SVG=Scalable Vector Graphic. You can only access SVG elements from a script within the SVG...which you don't have access to.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info - that's great to know and something I didn't realise.  If I wanted however to change the number of possible choices to 3 or 4, please could you advise on how to do that?  Is there a way to use one syntax that returns the item selected (sorry I'm used to doing things in VBA which would allow you to do this).